# blockchain.info api for tor hidden services

Tags: blockchain.info, tor

I would like to use blockchain.info "recieve payment" api for my hidden service, but would like opinion on the following considerations:

1. Will it be possible to use blockchain.info api for hidden services
2. Will blockchain.info allow tor connections
3. will the ip of my hidden server be compromised (broadcasted)

Answer (score 1):

Currently I do not think it is possible, atleast not without remaining "hidden".  What you could do is configure your bitcoind server to use a proxy: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Tor

Other alternatives you may want to look into is BitPay as they are currently working on a tor implementation: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/pull/210

Also [BitWasp](http://bitwasp.co) will be releasing their marketplace soon which you will be able to configure to run on the Tor network as well.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be asking about running the actual bitcoin client, just about talking with the blockchain.info website.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run bitcoind directly on your server and then interact with over its own JSON-RPC API. There are libraries for every programming language to do this.